# How to not pass on Tkinter bind event to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I have the issue that when I tried to set focus on something via a binding, the event was passed on:

```
entry_1.bind("<Return>",entry_2.focus_set)
```

But an error popped up because the event was passed on. So I tried Lambda instead, to not pass on an event:

```
entry_1.bind("<Return>",lambda :entry_2.focus_set())
```

The same error occurred. How can I stop the event being passed on?

Comment: by "passed on" you mean that the function was called with an "event" parameter? Yes, your function (or lambda) needs to be able to accept that argument.

Comment: The function is predefined, so it needed to be gotten rid of and not passed on, as it is definitely unable to accept that.

Answer (score 0):

```
entry_1.bind("<Return>",lambda event :entry_2.focus_set())
```

This passes on the event class straight to event, which does nothing, and thus, is ignored.